# How to find periods where 'connections' is 1 for different applications in a single dataset

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitoring

I have a set of 3 applications that update their state to CosmosDB.
From the CosmosDB the data is stored on Application Insights on change.

I am interested in periods of time where one of the applications has 1 or 0 connections instead of the expected 2.

The current query I use is:

```
| where operation_Name == "MyChangeLogFunction"
| where customDimensions.prop__Key == "asset-1"
| sort by timestamp desc
| extend telemetry = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.prop__Stream))
| project timestamp, v=toint(telemetry.open_connections)
| project timestamp, v_to=prev(v), v_from=v
| where v_from != v_to
```

But it's not a very clean query using prev(), and I need to repeat the query for all my assets manually.

Ideally, I would have a single query that would cluster the periods by number of connections, for each asset, so that my result would look like:

```
[asset-id] [open connections] [start time] [end time]
```

Is there a way to write such a query?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the [bin function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction) to create periods of time:

```
| where operation_Name == "MyChangeLogFunction"
| extend assetId = tostring(customDimensions.prop__Key)
| extend telemetry = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.prop__Stream))
| extend oc = toint(telemetry.open_connections)
| summarize sum(oc), max(oc), min(oc), avg(oc) by bin(timestamp, 1h), assetId
```

This will give you sum, min, avg and max of all open connections per 1 hour period per asset. In your case, you are interested if the avg is less than 2.